# cancel input box exits sub

Tags: vba

When i hit cancel i want it stop in its tracks and do nothing, ive managed to get it to stop if i press ok without entering a value, but when i hit cancel it doesnt stop and instead sends the value FALSE

```
Dim xht As Variant
If Intersect(Target, Range("D12:AS23")) Is Nothing Then
    Else
    If Worksheets("Calendar").Range("AT2") = Worksheets("Settings").Range("AQ6") Then
    xht = Application.InputBox("Insert your entitlement here", "Entitlement")
        If xht = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox ("User canceled!")
            Exit Sub
        Sheets("test").Range(Target.Address).Value = xht
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If xht = vbNullString Or xht = False Then`

Comment: `If VarType(xht) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub`

Comment: thanks lads that got it, so easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If xht = vbNullString Or xht = False Then

Thanks @BraX